# JavaScript/HTML/CSS: Затемнение фона при выборе

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

У меня при просмотре одного из элементов страницы должен затемняться фон и выходить модальное окно. Делаю я это так:

```
        app_view.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        // Здесь я задаю видимость модальному окну
        app__view__entry.style.display = 'flex';
        app__view__entry.style.zIndex = '11';

        // Здесь я работаю с затемняющим блоком
        wr_block.style.display = 'block';
        wr_block.style.zIndex = '10';
        wr_block.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        wr_block.style.position = 'absolute';
        wr_block.style.opacity = '0.7';
        document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
        }
```

Все нормально, но проблема в том, что он перематывает на начало текущее положение скролла. Как сделать так, чтобы скролл оставался на том же элементе, где он был выбран?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: А вообще проблема скорее всего в том, что вы на body вешаете `position:fixed`, тем самым вырывая его из потока документа. Если вы хотите добиться того, чтобы документ не прокручивался во время показа модального окна, вы можете повесить на body `overflow:hidden`.